# How can add a column autoincrement but this is not primary key or identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to add a counter by country when save a row, for example:

Table Country

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | France |
| 2 | Spain |

Table "Sales" -> Records sales by country

| Id | Category | numSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 4 |

```
_context.Sales.Add(register);
 _context.SaveChanges()
```

affter savechanges numsales is always on null

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try when defining an entity model to add:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Primary key

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int NonPrimaryKeyField { get; set; }
    // Other properties...
}
```

This will configure the NonPrimaryKeyField property to be generated by the database when a new record is inserted